# Trigger for validating URL column values in Mysql table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am having a table in PhpMyadmin, which have one column that takes url values. I dont want to do validation from PHP code/frontend. How can I achive this using trigger/procedure? I tried following trigger but getting error: "#1241 Operand should contain 3 column(s)"

```
CREATE TRIGGER `validate_url_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name`

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE str1 varchar(10);

DECLARE str2 varchar(10);

SET str1='http://';

SET str2='https://';

if(substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(REPLACE(new.url,str2,str1), '/',3),str1,-1),'.',-1) != 'com',substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(REPLACE(new.url,str2,str1), '/',3),str1,-1),'.',-3),substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(REPLACE(new.url,str2,str1), '/',3),str1,-1),'.',-2)) != '' then

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Can not insert';

END IF;

END
```

Comment: What have you tried previously, which hasn't worked for you?  Why don't you want to validate with PHP (which is server side, not front end)?  If you really need (for some odd requirement) to validate in MySQL, take a look at MySQL regular expressions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) and triggers (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) and use them together.  NOTE: I added this as a comment as I don't think it actually provides a full answer.

Comment: Seconding gabe3886's comment. Validation belongs in the middle tier PHP code. Data validation in the database layer (outside of referential integrity) should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: I dont want to do front end validation. i.e While getting inputs from user. Not even want to do validation during PHP code inserts into my database. I want it get validated at mysql /back end only

Comment: Wow, you're beyond confused. Databases are for handling and manipulating data, not for validation. Do you use guns to kill flies?

Comment: :D I just want to enter few records in table without help of any code....So I was trying to insert records in table from phpmyadmin. Can anyone tell me how to add conditions? (I dont mean check constraint here) I am learning trigger, procedures

Comment: The above comments by gabe3886, Nick, N.B. about validation belonging exclusively into PHP layer are plain wrong. PostgreSQL, Oracle and other databases ensure integrity of stored data by advanced constraints and triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got my answer on my own.

```
            CREATE TRIGGER `validate_work_url` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name`
             FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            IF new.url REGEXP "^(https?://|www.)[.A-Za-z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" THEN
                SET new.url = new.url;
            ELSE
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                                SET MESSAGE_TEXT =  "INCORRECT URL" ;
            END IF;
            END
```